# Check if the returned value is an integer if so return string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, int, algolia

I am using Algolia Search to receive a list of data (hits).

I get a cell parameter like the below;

```
cell.textLabel?.text = [String: Any](hit)?["im_code"] as? String
```

However, this could return a string or an int.  I would like to force this to a string.  I have tried to wrap it in a string but it did not work.

### Additional Notes

Unfortunately, Algolia's back end does not allow you to typecast values so it is not an option on the backend.

### Model Explanation

`[String: Any](hit)?["im_code"]` could return an `Int` or `String`. I need this to be always forced to string.

Comment: your code should show `String` or nil, but not `Int` or `String?` after casting is weird, why you are saying that shows `Int` or `String?`, in fact `UILabel.text` is `String?` type property

Comment: if the returned value is an int I need to put it as string

Answer (score 1):

You could cast the type to common protocol `CustomStringConvertible`, the `description` property returns the string representation:

```
let value = hit?["im_code"] as? CustomStringConvertible ?? ""
cell.textLabel?.text = value.description
```

Comment: this returns the int as a double.

Comment: Then your `Int` is a `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

You got a few options here:

```
let value = yourDict?["im_code"] // Assuming Any? as the type
```

**The Good**

```
if let value = value as? String {
    cell.textLabel?.text = value
} else if let value = value as? Int {
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(value)
}
```

**The Bad**

```
if let value = value {
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(value)"
}
```

**The Ugly**

```
let text: Any = (value as? String) ?? (value as? Int) ?? ""
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(text)"
```

Comment: let value = [String: Any](hit)?["im_code"]
                if let value = value as? String {
                cell.textLabel?.text = value
            } else if let value = value as? Int {
                cell.textLabel?.text = String(value)
            } returns nil